# Calling IEnumerator from an Interface class

Tags: c#, generics, interface, ienumerator

I am new to enumerating collections so forgive if this question sounds silly.

I have an class

```
public class PersonStuff : IPersonStuff, IEnumerable<User>
    {
        Person person = new Person();
        ...

        IEnumerator<Person> IEnumerable<Person>.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return (person as IEnumerable<Person>).GetEnumerator();
        }
}
```

As you can see, I am implementing two interfaces in the above: one being IPersonStuff and the other being IEnumerable.

The Person class is a simple getter/setter each type being of string e.g. name, address except dateofbirth which is DateTime.

And in my IPersonStuff I have this:

```
interface IPersonStuff
    {
        ...
        IEnumerator<Person>  IEnumerable<Person>.GetEnumerator();
    }
```

Once working, I would like to call it in the following manner (from any class):

```
    IPersonStuff personStuff = new PersonStuff();

    foreach (Person u in personStuff)
    {
        //this loop should iterate thru the elements.
    }
```

However, I get the following error:

- 'IEnumerable<...>.GetEnumerator': explicit interface declaration can only be declared in a class or struct

Basically I want to know how is it possible to call the IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() I have in the PersonStuff class through the IPersonStuff Interface.

Comment: Does your Person class implement IEnumerable (and if yes it should be some sort of collection) and the name will not be appropriate. What are you trying to achieve with the GetEnumerator function on declared in the PersonStuff?

Comment: the Person class does not implement IEnumerable but the PersonStuff does. I want to enumerate the items in Person object. PersonStuff creates the Person object and works with it.

Comment: The implementation you've described will iterate over multiple `Person` objects, not the items inside of a single person. If I'm misunderstanding, can you perhaps post an example of how you want to use the IEnumerable implementation, if you could get it to work?

Comment: @phoenix: updated on how I would like to call it.

Answer (score 5):

Is `IPersonStuff` itself collection-like, or just a bunch of properties?  If it's not collection-like, there's no need to make it enumerable.

I believe the error is due to `using System.Collections.Generic` but not `System.Collections` -- the non-generic `IEnumerable` is thus not in scope.

I think that if you want `IPersonStuff` to be enumerable then you can just have `IPersonStuff` inherit `IEnumerable<T>` (which in turn inherits `IEnumerable`).  Otherwise, I don't think you'll be able to use `foreach` over a reference to `IPersonStuff`.

**EDIT** Based on further comments and edits, it looks like `PersonStuff` is intended to be a collection-like [data access class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) for `Person`, with instantiation managed in [monostate](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MonostatePattern) fashion.

The monostate instantiation defeats the point of defining an interface `IPersonStuff`: if you always create it with `new PersonStuff()` in-line, then (bar [bytecode postprocessing](http://www.postsharp.org/)) there is no opportunity to use some non-default implementation of the interface.

I would suggest defining some sort of data access context object with properties representing each of your global entity collections, then pass that around in your choice of fashion -- using a parameter or accessor-based singleton is preferable to a monostate.  This object may then wrap a database connection, NHibernate session, or similar.

Comment: IPersonStuff sets/gets values for the object Person (and uses DB). Person is essentially a getter/setter class. I want to enumerate through items in the Person class.

Comment: I mean, I want to enumerate the items that the Person object holds.

Comment: btw: IPersonStuff is an Interface for PersonStuff. It just contains the methods for PersonStuff.

Comment: In that case, unless something else implements it or you're using it for COM interop, delete IPersonStuff altogether.

Comment: IPersonStuff is the interface class, I want to call the IEnumerable to be exposed in the Interface IPersonStuff. Is that possible? Amendments made to initial question.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error most probably because like what Jeffrey said you're missing a reference to `System.Collections.Generic` which has the non-generic `IEnumerable`. Once you have the correct reference you won't need the cast of `(person as IEnumerable)`.

On whether it should/can be type safe depends on your situation. If all elements of what you're enumerating through are of the same type (i.e. fixed class, interface or subclass) that you should/can use the type safe `IEnumerable`. But if say maybe you want to enumerate all the properties in Person (which sounds like what you might be attempting) and you're returning diff types then you'll have to use the non-generic `IEnumerable`.

If you are enumerating through the properties of your class then one nice trick is to use `yield return` for each property (instead of writing a custom class that implements IEnumerator) in Person.GetEnumerator();

Comment: Sorry, yes I have amended the initial question to take care of different types (non generic IEnumerable). Can I call that through the Interface class IPersonStuff?